# Check existing values in column to another dataframe and add lines

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, the first one:

```
City      Country
-----------------
NY            US
LA            US
Paris         France
Roma          Italy
```

second one:

```
Place        Score         ID_ref
----------------------------------
Paris         +1            0010 
US            +5            1000
Italy         -8            3020
```

The output should be:

```
Place        Score            ID_ref
------------------------------------
Paris         +1            0010 
France        +1            0010 
US            +5            1000
LA            +5            1000
NY            +5            1000
Italy         -8            3020
Roma          -8            3020
```

I wanted to solve it by doing a double loop but the first dataframe has 5 000 rows and the second 25 000.

So I don't think that a double loop is the best thing to do.

Comment: you could do `df1['ID_ref'] = '1000'` , `df1[Score'] = '+5'` and `df2.append(df1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because you are merging on 'country' or 'city':

```
df_out = pd.concat(
   [df_p.set_index(df_p['Country']).rename_axis('Place', axis=0).stack().reset_index().merge(df_2),
    df_p.set_index(df_p['City']).rename_axis('Place', axis=0).stack().reset_index().merge(df_2)],
   ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()[['Place','Score','ID_ref']]
df_out['Location'] = df_out['Location'].fillna(df_out['Place'])
df_out = df_out[['Location','Score','ID_ref']]

df_out
```

Output:

```
  Location  Score  ID_ref
0       NY      5    1000
1       US      5    1000
2       LA      5    1000
4     Roma     -8    3020
5    Italy     -8    3020
6    Paris      1      10
7    Paris      1      10
```

Comment: this doesn't match desired output, no?

Comment: also, are we sure it's a merge? could be an append too

Comment: Yeah... used merge to get records to matchup correctly.  I am not sure exactly how you are intending on using append.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, I have no matches. I tested line by line and the merge(df_2) found nothing to merge. ( and of course there is similar field to merge)

Comment: @ScottBoston because it seems like data from df1 is has dummy values, so you define them and then stitch them to df2 and sort by score, like I suggest in my comment under OP

Answer (score 0):

Try merging first, followed by concatenating as follows:

```
join1 = pd.merge(df, df1, left_on='Country', right_on='Place', how='left')
del join1['Place']
del join1['Country']
join1.columns = ['Place', 'Score', 'ID_ref']
result = join1.concat(df1)
```